# Why is $\lim_{x \to 0} (1+f(x))^\frac{1}{g(x)} = e^l$ where $l=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

My textbook states that if $f(x) \to 0$ as $x \to 0$  $$\lim_{x \to 0} (1+f(x))^\frac{1}{g(x)} = e^l$$ where $$l=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$$
I try to do this as follows and I get a different result
$$\lim_{x \to 0} (1+f(x))^\frac{1}{g(x)}= \lim_{x \to 0} ((1+f(x))^\frac{1}{f(x)})^\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$$
And now we take the exponent out of the limit to get
$$[\lim_{x \to 0} (1+f(x))^\frac{1}{f(x)}]^\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=e^l$$
Where $$l=\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$$
Am I doing something wrong here because of which my $l$ is different?

Comment: $(1+f(x))^\frac{1}{g(x)}= (1+f(x)^\frac{1}{f(x)})^\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ is wrong.

Comment: Does $f(x)$ tend to $0$ when $x$ tend to $0$?

Comment: @Bernard yes i forgot to add that. Edited it in now

Comment: @Kavi yes that was a typo

Comment: In last equality you need limit.

Comment: @zkutch yes but my question is why do i need limit

Comment: Without limit in last you haven't equality before last: in appropriate conditions $\lim a(x)^{b(x)}=(\lim a(x))^{\lim b(x)}$

Comment: Did you see the notion of equivalence of function?

Comment: @zkutch oh I did not know this. Can you send a link of its proof or something?

Comment: @Bernard I am not sure what you mean. Are you talking about equivalence of 2 functions? If so then 2 functions are equivalent iff the range and domain are the same and the rule of the functions must give the same value from the range for any value from the domain.

Comment: No, I mean the notion from asymptotic analysis. Roughly, two functions are equivalent in a neighbourhood of $0$ if their ratio tends to $1$ when $x$ tends to $0$ (best known example: $\sin x\sim_0 x$).

Comment: @Bernard alright so what about it? (Sorry if that seems rude)

Comment: Well, you have to determine the limit of the log, which is $\dfrac1{g(x)}\ln\bigl(1+f(x)\bigr)$ and it happens that $\ln(1+u)\sim_{u=0} u$, so the log is  equivalent near $0$ to $\dfrac1{g(x)}f(x)$. Let me add that two equivalent functions have the same limit.

Comment: @Anili. Generally it comes from theorem for composition of functions. I'll wrote source after a while.

Comment: @zkutch alright thanks!

Comment: @Bernard Oh I wasn't aware that 2 equipment functions have the same limit. Thank you!

Comment: @Anili.  John M.H. Olmsted - Advanced calculus-Prentice Hall, (1961), page 44 theorem for $f(\phi(t))$, where $f$ is continuous and $\phi$ have limit. For this case this is enough, though there is theorem in more weak assumptions.

Comment: @zkutch Alright will check it out thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are taking the limit with respect to $x$, so the RHS should not depend on $x$. Then you arrive at $\lim_{x \to 0} ((1+f(x))^\frac{1}{f(x)})^\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ and took the limit inside the bracket, which is not correct, since the limit will only act on the function inside the bracket. Note you can only write the limit inside a function if it exists and the function is continuous.

For example we know that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}=e,$ but $\left(\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)^{n}=1^{n}$ since the limit acts only inside the brackets.

---

Let

$$L=\lim_{x \to 0} (1+f(x))^\frac{1}{g(x)}$$

then $$\ln L = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\ln\left((1+f(x))^{\frac{1}{g(x)}}\right) \quad(1)$$
$$\ln L = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\ln(1+f(x))}{g(x)}$$

$$\ln L = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\ln(1+f(x))}{f(x)}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$$
$$\implies L=e^{\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}}$$

provided $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ exist, and where I used the fact that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\ln(1+f(x))}{f(x)}=1$, which can be shown by expanding in power series. Indeed $\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{\ln(1+t)}{t}=1$. Also in $(1)$ the continuity of $\ln$ and the fact that the limit inside this function exists have been used.

Comment: In $\left(\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)^{n}$ expression $n$ inside outer brackets is bound variable and have nothing  in common with $n$ outside outer brackets - may be it's worth to emphasize this.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the simple explanation!

Comment: You're very welcome! :-). As mentioned by zkutch, when we take the limit inside the brackets, it has nothing to do with the common $n$ outside the brackets.

Answer (score 2):

**Note**: we must have $f(x)>-1$ for every $x\in\text{dom}[f]$ for $(1+f(x))^\frac{1}{g(x)}$ to be well defined.

If $f$ is nonzero in a sufficiently small interval $I$ around $0$, we can write
\begin{align}
(1+f(x))^\frac{1}{g(x)} &= e^{\frac{1}{g(x)}\ln\left(1+f(x)\right)}\\
&= e^{\frac{1}{g(x)}\ln\left(1+f(x)\right)}\\
&= e^{\frac{1}{g(x)}\left[\ln\left(1+f(x)\right)-\ln(1)\right]}\\
&= e^{\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\cdot\frac{\ln\left(1+f(x)\right)-\ln(1)}{f(x)}}\\
\end{align}

Note the similarity between the expression

$$\frac{\ln\left(1+f(x)\right)-\ln(1)}{f(x)}$$

and the difference quotient

$$\frac{\ln\left(1+h\right)-\ln(1)}{h}$$

In fact, since $f(x)\to 0$ as $x\to 0$, it makes sense that we should have

\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln\left(1+f(x)\right)-\ln(1)}{f(x)} &= \left[\frac{d}{dx}\ln(x)\right]_{x=1}\\
&= 1
\end{align}

This is proven at the bottom of my answer. Taking it as a given here, we can combine it with $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)/g(x)=l$ to get

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\cdot\frac{\ln\left(1+f(x)\right)-\ln(1)}{f(x)}\right)=l$$

It follows from the continuity of the exponential function that

$$\lim_{x\to 0}e^{\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\cdot\frac{\ln\left(1+f(x)\right)-\ln(1)}{f(x)}}=e^l$$

**Proof of the limit**: Fix an arbitrary $\varepsilon>0$. We want to show that there's a $\delta>0$ such that for every real $x$ where our expression is well-defined,

$$0<|x-0|<\delta\implies\left|\frac{\ln\left(1+f(x)\right)-\ln(1)}{f(x)}\right|<\varepsilon$$

We know that $\ln$ is differentiable at $1$, so there's a $\delta_1>0$ such that for every sufficiently small $h$,

$$0<|h-0|<\delta_1\implies\left|\frac{\ln\left(1+h\right)-\ln(1)}{h}\right|<\varepsilon$$

We know that $f(x)\to 0$ as $x\to 0$. If we assume further that $f$ is nonzero in a neighborhood around $0$, then there's a $\delta>0$ such that

$$0<|x-0|<\delta\implies 0<\left|f(x)-0\right|<\delta_1$$

Thus, if $0<|x-0|<\delta$, then $0<\left|f(x)-0\right|<\delta_1$, so

$$\left|\frac{\ln\left(1+f(x)\right)-\ln(1)}{f(x)}\right|<\varepsilon$$

This argument applies to every positive $\varepsilon$, so we've proven that

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln\left(1+f(x)\right)-\ln(1)}{f(x)}=1$$

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detailed explanation!

Comment: @Anili I'm glad you found it helpful :)